# Dynamic RETURN EXECUTE QUERY with ILIKE in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql

The search filter in the function below doesn't seem to work. If I don't provide a `search` parameter, it works, otherwise I get no recordset back. I'm assuming I am making a mess of the single-quoting and ILIKE, but not sure how to re-write this properly. Suggestions?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_operator_basic_by_operator(
  _operator_id      UUID DEFAULT NULL,
  _search           TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
  _page_number      INTEGER DEFAULT 1,
  _page_size        INTEGER DEFAULT 10,
  _sort_col         TEXT DEFAULT 'username',
  _sort_dir         TEXT DEFAULT 'asc',
  _include_deleted  BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE
)
RETURNS TABLE (
  id                  UUID,
  party_id            UUID,
  party_name          TEXT,
  username            VARCHAR(32),
  profile_picture_uri VARCHAR(512),
  first_name          VARCHAR(64),
  last_name           VARCHAR(64),
  street              VARCHAR(128),
  specifier           VARCHAR(128),
  city                VARCHAR(64),
  state               VARCHAR(2),
  zipcode             VARCHAR(9),
  primary_email       CITEXT,
  primary_phone       VARCHAR(10),
  secondary_email     CITEXT,
  secondary_phone     VARCHAR(10),
  last_login          TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
  created             TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
  deleted             TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
)
AS $$
DECLARE
  _offset BIGINT;
BEGIN

  IF (_page_number < 1 OR _page_number IS NULL) THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION '_page_number cannot be null or less than 1.';
  END IF;

  IF (_page_size < 1 OR _page_size IS NULL) THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION '_page_size cannot be null or less than 1.';
  END IF;

  IF (_sort_dir <> 'asc' AND _sort_dir <> 'desc') THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION '_sort_dir must be "asc" or "desc".';
  END IF;

  _offset := (_page_size * (_page_number-1)); 

  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE '
  SELECT
    o.id,
    p.id,
    p.party_name,
    o.username,
    o.profile_picture_uri,
    o.first_name,
    o.last_name,
    o.street,
    o.specifier,
    o.city,
    o.state,
    o.zipcode,
    o.primary_email,
    o.primary_phone,
    o.secondary_email,
    o.secondary_phone,
    o.last_login,
    o.created,
    o.deleted
  FROM
    operator o
  LEFT JOIN
    party p ON o.party_id = p.id
  WHERE ( -- include all or only those active, based on _include_deleted
    $1 OR o.deleted > statement_timestamp()
  )
  AND o.party_id IN ( -- limit to operators in same party
    SELECT oi.party_id FROM operator oi WHERE oi.id = $2
  )
  AND ( -- use optional search filter
      $3 IS NULL 
    OR
      o.username ILIKE ''%$3%''
    OR
      o.first_name ILIKE ''%$3%''
    OR
      o.last_name ILIKE ''%$3%''
    OR
      o.primary_email ILIKE ''%$3%''
    )
  ORDER BY ' || quote_ident(_sort_col) || ' ' || _sort_dir || '
  LIMIT
    $4
  OFFSET
    $5'
  USING _include_deleted, _operator_id, _search, _page_size, _offset;
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings handles as is, you should to pass ready to use values:

```
EXECUTE '... o.username ILIKE $3 ...' using ..., '%' || _search || '%', ...
```

Answer (score 4):

The parameter is inserted as a text with quotes, so you should use it this way:

```
...
o.username ILIKE concat(''%'', $3, ''%'')
...
```

Personally I would use `format()` and dollar-quotes.

Comment: I this error `ERROR: operator is not unique: unknown % unknown LINE 12: OR job_class ILIKE (concat(''%'', $3, ''%'')) ^ HINT: Could not choose a best candidate operator. You might need to add explicit type casts.`